# How do I validate a password field in Struts 1?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-validation

I am making a registration form.

I need to check if both the password fields are the same.

```
<validator name="twofields"
           classname="com.mysite.StrutsValidator"
           method="validateTwoFields"
           msg="errors.twofields"/>

<field property="password"
       depends="required,twofields">

    <arg position="0" key="typeForm.password.displayname"/>
    <var>
       <var-name>secondProperty</var-name>
       <var-value>password2</var-value>
    </var>
</field>
```

Method

```
public class StrutsValidator {

    public static boolean validateTwoFields(
            Object bean,
            ValidatorAction va,
            Field field,
            ActionErrors errors,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            ServletContext application) {

        String value = ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString(
            bean,
            field.getProperty());
        String sProperty2 = field.getVarValue("secondProperty");
        String value2 = ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString(
            bean,
            sProperty2);

        if (!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(value)) {
            try {
                if (!value.equals(value2)) {
                    errors.add(field.getKey(),
                               Resources.getActionError(
                                   application,
                                   request,
                                   va,
                                   field));

                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                errors.add(field.getKey(),
                           Resources.getActionError(   //This line is giving an error.
                               application,
                               request,
                               va,
                               field));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried this, but it's giving an error. The method `getActionError(ServletContext, HttpServletRequest, ValidatorAction, Field)` is undefined for the type Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your exact Struts version? At least according to [Struts 1.1 API documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/struts/validator/Resources.html#getActionError%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,%20org.apache.commons.validator.Field%29), the `Resources.getActionError` method signature is the following:

```
getActionError( 
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,   
    org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction va,
    org.apache.commons.validator.Field field
)
```

This would indicate that you need to remove the application parameter from your method call:

```
errors.add(
    field.getKey(),
    Resources.getActionError(
        request,
        va,
        field));
```